# pin several elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make some elements to pin while scorlling in order to form something, I'm using Jquery waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/) and I tried to optimize the code to run for several elements it works fine with Firefox, Chrome and Safari but can't make it run on the infamous Internet Explorer. the HTML goes like this:

```
<div style="height: 300px;">TODO write content</div>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="images/image1.png"/>
            <img src="images/image2.png"/>
            <img  src="images/image3.png"/>
            <img  src="images/image4.png"/>
</div>
<!--This are just for adding some space for the scrolling-->
<div style="height: 300px;">TODO write content</div>
<div style="height: 300px;">TODO write content</div>
<div style="height: 300px;">TODO write content</div>
<div style="height: 300px;">END</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.my-sticky-element.stuck {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
```

}

The custom JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('.container').find('img').each(function() {
                imgnum+=1
                var $this=$(this);
                var stickyclass="my-sticky-element";
                $this.addClass("my-sticky-element");
                console.log(stickyclass);
                $this.waypoint('sticky', {
                    offset: 30 // Apply "stuck" when element 30px from top

                });
            });
```

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/PHr4t/

Comment: Can you provide more information about why it does not work in IE. What you're expecting to happen, and what does happen would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to stack several elements  (in this case the rectangle images) by pinning them when they reach cetain point in order to form another figure. When they reach the offset 30 (30 px from the top) their position is supossed to change to fixed.